# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos de un usuario utilizando SESSION?

Tags: php, mysql

Hola estoy intentando obtener los datos de un usuario con una sesión, por ejemplo para cuando inicio sesión desde la página web, esto es lo que intenté y obtengo este error "Undefined index ID"

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        header("Location: home/");
    }
```

¿Cómo puedo saber la ID del usuario?

También lo que estoy intentando realizar, es que cuando el usuario inicie sesión, pueda obtener más datos de su cuenta, por ejemplo, obtener cuanta cantidad de dinero tiene, que genero eligió etc etc.

Comment: Revisa el nombre de la columna en la tabla de la base de datos, a lo mejor es Id o iD o ID en lugar de id (case sensitive)

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc te retorna un array, creo que en ese caso deberiar utilizar ```$_SESSION['username'] = $row[0]['username'];```

Comment: @masterguru Es correctamente como digo, "id"

Comment: @MIGUELLOPEZARIZA sigue sin funcionar, no puedo obtener la ID del usuario, o intento obtener otro dato, como por ejemplo "dinero"

Comment: En lugar de redirigir, agrega estas dos líneas: `var_dump($row); die();` y edita la respuesta para agregar lo que se muestra en pantalla, aunque supongo que eso te dará una pista para obtener el dato deseado.

Comment: obtengo esto @Triby array(7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "9" ["username"]=> string(6) "ROBLOX" ["email"]=> string(19) "asdujanda@gmail.com" ["nacimiento"]=> string(0) "" ["genero"]=> string(1) "0" ["robux"]=> string(3) "500" ["password"]=> string(32) "720ab3b7ebd6c1171943f3349d7fc71f" }

Comment: Debajo de las etiquetas, a la izquierda de tus datos de usuario, hay varios enlaces, puedes hacer clic en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/512391/edit) para agregar más información en la pregunta. Por favor modifica para teclear el mensaje de error completo (incluyendo número de línea) y especificando qué linea es. Por cierto, ¿tienes un `session_start();` al inicio del script?

Comment: @Triby no tengo ningún session_start(); y ya edité la publicación

Comment: Entonces ese es el problema, no puedes hacer uso de las variables de sesión si no las activas primero con `session_start();` y quiero suponer que el error que mencionas no es en el código que pusiste en la pregunta, sino en `home/`, al intentar acceder a los datos del usuario.

Comment: @Triby Para cuando intento acceder a los datos del usuario utilizo esto: ```<?php echo $_SESSION['dinero']; ?>``` pero no lo estoy obteniendo y aparece el mismo error

Comment: ah, y ya agregué eso de session_start();

Comment: Entonces debes crear esa variable cuando el usuario inicia sesión, sería algo como `$_SESSION['dinero'] = $row['dinero'];` y debes hacerlo para cada dato que necesites, por supuesto, validando que el nombre sea el mismo en la tabla de usuario.

Comment: @user264129 el `session_start();` debe ir antes de invocar a las variables de $_SESSION y en todos los scripts donde las uses, no solo en este